# How to hide list of installed deps from tox console output?

Tags: python, tox

I am trying to simplify the console output of tox and to hide the list of installed packages, ideally to hide them if there are no errors installing them.

Here is the current output

```
tox -e py27                                                                                                                                           
py27 installed: alabaster==0.7.9,...<VERY LONG LIST..
py27 runtests: ...
```

I tried to add `install_command = pip install -q {opts} {packages}` but it did had no effect.

Answer (score 4):

With `tox >= 2.4` you can use the `list_dependencies_command` parameter (http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-list_dependencies_command).

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals=echo
list_dependencies_command=echo
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that at this moment this is a tox bug https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/601